# Open an app part way down a NavigationController's view stack

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am working my way through the book "Beginning iPhone Development" and understand the basic view push concept. However Apple's iPhone UI design guide states that I should re-open my application at the previous app-exit view. How can I boot a NavigationController so that it defaults to a child view and yet has a view stack that returns to the application's root view?

By analogy with the iPhone email app, 80% of the time my users would start at an inbox child view but will need to navigate up to an "overview" root view at times.

A solution?

I thought the animated property of pushViewController() just controlled the visual effect of a view open but the docs state "Pass NO if you are setting up a navigation controller before its view is displayed". I hope this means I can push hidden views into the controller's stack up to the default app-open view and then animate the final view display?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to store the stack somewhere and go to the proper view on launch.

That being said, you don't *have* to do this. It only makes sense for some applications.

See also: [Preserving application state across restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329511/preserving-application-state-across-restarts)